# Azure analytics workspace as source in a alerts

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I have a hard time here understanding what a log analytics workspace is. As I have a requirement to monitor 7 application insigths out of many. Send emails if some of them throws exceptions. I can see in alerts you can only select a single application insight. And I dont want to create 7 alerts. So my plan was to create a analytics workspace. I havent found anyway to bind application insights to a workspace. Is that possible? I can see you in alerts can choose a analytics workspace as source, but what does that mean? Sounds like you some how can group data in that specific workspace?

[image]

I can see when I create a new Application Insight service i have the option to choose a workspace, but what with existing?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean when you say " Send emails if some of them throws exceptions"? the exception is about the Application insights itself, or just the exceptions in the exception table in Application insights?

Comment: If there is exceptions in AI.

Comment: you mean if there are any exceptions logged into AI?

Comment: Yes. I have 5 different application insights. My applications logs into those. When an exception occurs in some of them I want to send an email with alerts. In alerts you can only pick one application insight. And I dont want to create 5 alerts. I would like to gather all of the 5 application isights into one container. As I understand it workspaces are such a container? But how do I load the data into the workspace? So I can select a workspace in the alerts with data from all 5 insights.

Comment: yes, you can use`Workspace-based Application Insights resources`, see answer below:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as per your requirement, you can [create the Workspace-based Application Insights resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource), or [connect the existing classical AI to azure log analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource). And of course, these 6 AI should connect to the same azure log analytics.

After you have the the `Workspace-based Application Insights resources`, the logs are logged into both the `AI` and the `azure log analytics`. So when you create an alert rule, select the azure log analytics, and create a `custom log search alert rule`. That can totally meet your requirement.

And you should also understand [the table scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/apm-tables#table-structure) between AI and Azure log Analytics. For example, in AI, the exceptions are logged in `exceptions` table; but if it's connected to azure log analytics, then in log analytics, the exceptions are in `AppSystemEvents` table.

Comment: That is exactly what I want, perfect! Just one thing. The article is based on when you create a new application insight you can pick your workspace. But what do you do with allready existing insights? I havent found anyway to add them to  anew workspace:(

Comment: Sorry you number to links explain that. I try it out.

Comment: @ThomasSegato, np. Please let me know if any issues:).

Comment: If you knew how many hours I have been looking for that little migrate link in the button of the properties page!!!!! THANKS a lot!